# not getting radiobutton 'value' from other function(def) in tkinter, how to achieve this without using class?

Tags: python, tkinter

Not getting radiobutton 'value' from other function(def) in tkinter, how to achieve this without using class?

In this case a=a1.get() is not taking value from command (of sub1 button) in ques1() function.

from tkinter import *

```
global root
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
a1=StringVar()
ans1=StringVar()

def ans1():
    a=a1.get()  #not getting it from ques1()
    print(a)

def ques1():
    root.destroy()
    global window1
    window1=Tk()
    window1.geometry("500x500")
    question1=Label(window1, text="How many Planets are there in Solar System").grid()
    q1r1=Radiobutton(window1, text='op 1', variable=a1, value="correct").grid()
    q1r2=Radiobutton(window1, text='op 2', variable=a1, value="incorrect").grid()
    sub1=Button(window1, text="Submit", command=ans1).grid()
    next1But=Button(window1, text="Next Question", command=ques2).grid()

def ques2():
    window1.destroy()
    window2=Tk()
    window2.geometry("500x500")
    question2=Label(window2, text="How many Planets are there in Solar System").grid()
    next2But=Button(window2, text="Next Question")


button=Button(root,text="Start Test", command=ques1).grid()
```

Comment: remove `global root` from your code. This is doing nothing for you. `root` already exist in the global name space.

Answer (score 2):

This is a side effect from using `Tk` more than once in a program. Basically, "a1" is tied to the "root" window, and when you destroy "root", "a1" will no longer work.

You have a couple options:

1. Keep the same window open all the time, and swap out the *Frames* instead.
2. Use `Toplevel()` to make new windows instead of `Tk`.

Option 1 seems the best for you. Here it is:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
a1=StringVar(value='hippidy')
ans1=StringVar()

def ans1():
    a=a1.get()  #not getting it from ques1()
    print(repr(a))

def ques1():
    global frame
    frame.destroy() # destroy old frame
    frame = Frame(root) # make a new frame
    frame.pack()

    question1=Label(frame, text="How many Planets are there in Solar System").grid()
    q1r1=Radiobutton(frame, text='op 1', variable=a1, value="correct").grid()
    q1r2=Radiobutton(frame, text='op 2', variable=a1, value="incorrect").grid()
    sub1=Button(frame, text="Submit", command=ans1).grid()
    next1But=Button(frame, text="Next Question", command=ques2).grid()

def ques2():
    global frame
    frame.destroy() # destroy old frame
    frame = Frame(root) # make a new frame
    frame.pack()

    question2=Label(frame, text="How many Planets are there in Solar System").grid()
    next2But=Button(frame, text="Next Question")

frame = Frame(root) # make a new frame
frame.pack()
button=Button(frame,text="Start Test", command=ques1).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Also, don't be scared of classes. They are great.

Also, the way you have a widget initialization and layout on the same line is known to cause bugs. Use 2 lines always. So instead of this

```
button=Button(frame,text="Start Test", command=ques1).grid()
```

Use this:

```
button=Button(frame,text="Start Test", command=ques1)
button.grid()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a single instance of `Tk`. Variables and widgets created in one cannot be accessed from another.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some common mistakes. You are creating a new window on each question. It is not a good idea. You can use `Toplevel` but I will suggest you to use the `root`. You can destroy all of your previous widgets and place new ones. When the first question, both radiobuttons are unchecked and return 0 when none is selected. You are creating the buttons in `Window1` so you will have to tie it with your var.

```
from tkinter import *
global root
root=Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
a1=StringVar(root)
a1.set(0)  #unchecking all radiobuttons
ans1=StringVar()

def ans1():
    a=a1.get()
    print(a)

def ques1():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy() #destroying all widgets
    question1=Label(root, text="How many Planets are there in Solar System").grid()
    q1r1=Radiobutton(root, text='op 1', variable=a1, value="correct").grid()
    q1r2=Radiobutton(root, text='op 2', variable=a1, value="incorrect").grid()
    sub1=Button(root, text="Submit", command=ans1).grid()
    next1But=Button(root, text="Next Question", command=ques2).grid()
def ques2():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    question2=Label(root, text="How many Planets are there in Solar System").grid()
    next2But=Button(root, text="Next Question")


button=Button(root,text="Start Test", command=ques1)
button.grid()
```